# paste selected text: switch right and middle click

Tags: command-line, configuration, mouse, usability, clipboard

Is there a way of choosing between right and middle click for pasting?
There are ways of for disabling it, I want to change the behaviour

[How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a terminal and paste this so the right button will behave as the middle (and the middle will behave as the right):
    xmodmap -e "pointer 1 3 2"

Comment: works with `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 3 2"`, thx

I was actually after the paste functionality only, would be nice to keep the right click in place.

Comment: I will try to find a better solution for you ;-)

Comment: google suggests not much. for a touchpad the default middle-click-paste is a bug not a feature...

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves you to download source code of gnome terminal and apply the [patch](http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/right-button-paste.patch) and then you will need to build a package which will build deb packages and then you can just install from those packages.

For more clear instructions you can view this [page](http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/index.html).