# How to turn off copy function when pressing mouse wheel?

Tags: clipboard, mouse-wheel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste)

How to turn off copy function when pressing MOUSE2 (wheel) button ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these link may be these can help

[How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste)

Or

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input