# How to paste using middle mouse in rstudio running in linux?

Tags: mouse, r

How to enable the middle button mouse to paste in rstudio running in linux?

My middle button mouse is working for pasting to R running in linux terminal.

Comment: I have asked this question on the RStudio support pages: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/205561328--LINUX-Enable-x-selection-paste-with-middle-mouse-button-

Comment: X-selection-paste and X-clipboard-paste are to different things, though they might seems the same, due to the fact that you normally select something before copying. rstudio probably does not support X-selection-paste, I remember some Java Swing apps behave like that.  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225874/why-is-the-middle-button-mapped-to-pasting

Comment: Have you tried using a clipboard manager like copyQ? https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/releases