# How do I get my old xmodmap settings back?

Tags: xmodmap, mouse-wheel

I wanted to disable "paste" action on mouse wheel click, and I use the code below(from this msg: https://askubuntu.com/a/55988);

xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

It worked but also disabled "open in new tab" function in browser. 
Now I just want to get my old damn settings back!

Can anyone explain what should I do clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

just replace the 25 with 2.

Or, if you added this to your ~/.Xmodmap file, delete the line.