# How to disable mouse wheel paste?

Tags: 16.04, unity, mouse, mouse-wheel

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with the Unity desktop. The middle wheel of my mouse inserts text whenever I klick it. This is quite a disturbing feature, as the mouse I use has quite a fragile mouse wheel button, so I constantly insert text when scrolling through text. I already tried to disable this feature within the `unity-tweak-tool`, but I couldn't find any entry for the mouse wheel button.

Is there a way to disable this mouse wheel click feature?

Comment: @pomsky Nope, not a dupplicate regarding your link. Can't install the mentionned software due to security risks. I am more looking forward of changing some settings somewhere in a configuration file.

Comment: What software? There are more than 20 answers, not a single one is applicable in your case?

Comment: @pomsky This did the trick. Found somewhere in one of the 20 answers. Installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and disabled exactly this middle mouse button functionalty. https://askubuntu.com/a/872165/359858

Comment: Great! Don't forget to upvote it in that case ;-)

Comment: @pomsky Already did, I'm number 3. ;) Cheers mate.