# Change behavior of middle mouse button in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, click-policy

I have the same problem that was [asked in 2018 about Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036438/turn-off-middle-mouse-button-in-ubuntu-16-04-with-unity?rq=1).  I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to check if there is anything new to know about.

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IIL05.  It comes with a mouse pad built in.

In using Firefox, Open Office and other programs, I experience undesired insertions of text.  What I suppose is happening is that I am pressing on a middle-click button.  I don't have any particular need for a middle-click button.  And the keyboard layout is such that my left thumb ends up clicking on the center of the mouse pad.  Anyways, I am not sure but I suppose that I have a middle-click button and at unexpected times it inserts text when I press on it.

I installed Gnome Tweaks and turned off the middle-click button as [described here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux). But that didn't help, although the program's interface says that middle-click insertion is turned off.

Please, what can I do to prevent these insertions from happening?

Is there a way to make my middle-click button simply behave like my left-click button?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: A couple of days ago, I tried the solution that I linked to.  The problem has gone away.