# xsel -cp clears the selected text

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xsel

I'm trying to disable middle click to paste, and having tried many options and none working effectively, I am trying to use a script with xsel is a loop to clear the contents of the primary clipbord.

The command I'm trying to loop is

```
xsel -cp
```

However the issue with this is that I can no longer select any text while the script is active, because xsel clears the selection constantly.

My question is, is there any way to clear the contents of the primary clipboard without clearing the selected text?

### Edit

I've remapped the middle mouse button, but I'd rather still be able to use all the other things that this button does.

I've tried patching gtk3, but that was unsuccessful for unknown reasons.

I saw that gnome tool tool has an option to disable it, but I'm not running gnome (I'm using cinnamon)

Comment: What about https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472464/61798? And more here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste

Comment: @DKBose please see the edit. I've tried all those things already, this is the only viable option for me, so I'd like to get it working

Comment: Did you try the solution using `sxhkd`?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, it makes no difference.