# gedit: Clipboard content gets pasted into text being edited without user warning

Tags: gedit

gedit is pasting some content (possibly clip board) into text being edited without warning me. And this happens when I am editing source code (*.f90 files) making it very dangerous.

This used to happen within Linux system previously.

Recently I found the copy of the same text in four spots on one of my source files but this text was from an email that I typed in Outlook of a Windows machine. 
I assume this happened because I access Linux from this Windows machine as virtual system.

This is bizarre, dangerous and very annoying.

But why is it happening?

Does anyone know what might be the source of the problem?

Is it likely that  I am touching the mouse in a weird way to make it think that I want to paste something?  If so what could that be?

Comment: Do you have shortcut keys to copy and paste between Windows clipboard and Linux VM?

Comment: answer to WinEunuuchs2Unix:  I am not aware of them. I am not using them.

Comment: In that case I would ask your system administrator to disable the function that allows copying in Windows and pasting in Linux. You don't need the functionality and it appears to have undesirable side effects.

Comment: I understand but this was also happening within Linux.  How would I solve that problem?  Is there something in gedit that allows this to happen?  BTW thank you for replying.

Comment: "*Is it likely that I am touching the mouse in a weird way to make it think that I want to paste something?* : Are you pressing the middle-click button? Then it's a *feature*.

Comment: I almost never hit middle button. Indeed I have just done it and it seems to insert always the same text :    https://software.opensuse.org.package/gedit   (gedit was open).  Is that what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, it's a feature, pastes the last selected text. Possible duplicate of [How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste)