# Random pieces of text pasted in code files

Tags: matlab, clipboard, julia-lang

Quite often, when I'm writing small programs in e.g. MATLAb or Atom/Juno (on Ubuntu 20.04), I get errors because a a certain variable is not recognized. Upon taking a closer look, the origin seems to be pieces of text that are randomly pasted somewhere in the middle of the code. This could be things that I copied somewhere earlier, but I'm not sure if that's always the case.

Of course, this is quite annoying, and the big risk is that sometime it will not just throw an error but actually affect the output.

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the mouse wheel, that I accidentally pressed sometimes.

For turning this off, see [How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste)