# Disable middle-click paste on kde-plasma

Tags: kubuntu, kde

The last thing I highlighted is pasted when I middle-click. I changed it so it only shows the last thing that I copied instead of highlighted, but for middle click it's still like that. I want to disable middle-click paste the last highlighted thing to the last thing I copied instead. It also gives me a fear that what if I accidentally pased `rm -rf /*` >.<
I have OCD.

Comment: I personally would never recommend a question from 2010 as being duplicated, especially if it has 38 answers. This is just wasting the OP's time. Which of the 38 answers would you recommend the OP try first for use with **kde-plasma-desktop on Ubuntu 22.04?** Besides the word duplicate is defined as an exact copy, which this question is not.

Comment: The duplicated question and many of it's answers mention Gnome and Gnome Tweaks. My understanding is that these do not work on kde-plasma-desktop. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I agree..

Comment: The OP can try the answers which mention KDE or Kubuntu (of which there are a few, a couple even posted within the past year). I see no reason to re-open this until those have been tried and found wanting simply for the sake of duplicating content again and again.

Comment: @muru I searched the question referred to. First link to a solution resulted in "404 Not Found. KDE mentioned in a comment referred to Manjaro.  Second answer that referred to KDE has a score of 1 and the third answer has a score of -1. Only one of these questions referred to KDE-Plasma.

Comment: And [that second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1383469/158442) was posted just last year, of course it hasn't had time to gain more votes - and here are people like you, @C.S.Cameron who just looked at it, didn't even try and is willing to simply ignore some user's effort at helping others just because it's new and hasn't got many votes yet. Please don't bully low scoring users and posts like that. Surely we can do better.

Comment: I am not sure the OP would ever make it all the way down the page to an answer that has sixteen higher rated answers before it. This question is at least specific to kde-plasma Desktop, which in itself, by definition, makes it not a duplicate.