# Kubuntu Middle Mouse Button pasting last highlighted text

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde

Pressing the middle mouse button automatically pastes whatever the last highlighted text was. Note that I'm not talking about the clipboard or copied text, just the simple act of highlighting text seems to forever keep it in some invisible buffer to be spat out every time I press the button.

This is, in a word, infuriating, and I cannot find any function to disable it. Note that I am not asking to disable the button entirely, just this incredibly annoying function.

I have followed the instructions in this post: [How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste/1387263#1387263) to the best of my ability, and it doesn't seem to work.