# Middle click paste disable globally

Tags: 22.04, paste

Running Ubuntu 22.04. I want to disable all forms of middle click paste, but keep middle button working for scroll, tab closing, etc. I just want it not to paste anything anywhere.

I tried many suggested solutions, the one that worked the most so far is using the Gnome tweak tool as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/872165/823631). It works partially, e.g. in the Gnome terminal app now it is fine but in other apps such as LyX or LibreOffice Writer the middle click still pastes stuff.

Don't know if this matters, I am running Ubuntu with Xorg (not Wayland).